# How can one create an OWL 2 annotation with the OWL-API

Tags: rdf, jena, owl, owl-api

I want to create the following

```
  s p xlt .
  _:x rdf:type owl:Axiom .
  _:x owl:annotatedSource s .
  _:x owl:annotatedProperty p .
  _:x owl:annotatedTarget xlt
```

I saw somehwere the code for doing so in Jena, I would like to know if there is a way to do using the OWL-API?  The statement does not have to exist in the actual ontology. It is meant more to represent provenance.

Answer (score 1):

An annotated axiom in an ontology is still an axiom in the ontology.  If you really want something for provenance, you're going to have to do something a bit different, I think.

In your case, though, it looks like you just want an ObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom that has some annotations.  You'll just want to use the [OWLDataFactory](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLDataFactory.html) method [getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLDataFactory.html#getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom%28org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLObjectPropertyExpression,%20org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLIndividual,%20org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLIndividual,%20java.util.Set%29) which takes a property, individual, object, and a set of [OWLAnnotations](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLAnnotation.html).

The [OWLAPI documentation](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/documentation.html) also includes a large number of examples, including one that [shows how to create and read annotations](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/master/contract/src/test/java/org/coode/owlapi/examples/Examples.java#L1202), which may or may not be instructive in your case.